# Gorm Can't Insert Value into Sqlite

Tags: database, sqlite, go, web, go-gorm

I use dao layer to init sqlitedb and try to insert a col into db in main.go

The Problem is When the main.go is finish and the database is created.But No any data in db..

my model.go is here

```
package model

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
```

and my gorm dao.go is here

```
package dao

import (
    "go_blog/model"
    "log"

    "gorm.io/driver/sqlite"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Manager interface {
    AddUser(user *model.User)
}

type manager struct {
    db *gorm.DB
}

var Mgr Manager

func init() {
    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("database/blog.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Failed to INIT db:", err)
    }
    Mgr = &manager{db: db}
    db.AutoMigrate(&model.User{})
    log.Fatal("Init DB Successful")

}

func (mgr *manager) AddUser(user *model.User) {
    mgr.db.Create(user)
}
```

when I use main.go to run the Mgr.AddUser function,I look into sqlite db,but the DB is no any data in there...So Confuse..

main.go is here

```
package main

import (
    "go_blog/dao"
    "go_blog/model"
)

func main() {
    user := model.User{
        Username: "tom",
        Password: "123",
    }
    dao.Mgr.AddUser(&user)
}
```

Comment: You omitted proper error handling from your Go code. Don't do that.

Comment: @mkopriva Oh，How Studied I am，I Should type the log.print,Thank you very very much!!!!!!!

Comment: See: https://gorm.io/docs/error_handling.html. Look at the value of `mgr.db.Create(user).Error`. If that doesn't help try turning on debugging: https://gorm.io/docs/logger.html#Debug

Comment: @mkopriva I change log.fatal to log.print.It works now,You solve my problem!!!!!! I will learn the error_handling, thx again!!!!